# Finding the Missing Sequence SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CNo Wno Lno
12  1    1
12  1    2
12  2    3
12  3    15
9   1    1
13  1    1
13  2    2
13  3    5
10  1    1
10  1    2
10  1    3
10  2    4
11  1    1
```

for Cno i need the missing sequence numbers in Lno
Eg:
for Cn0=12
the line no is missing from 4 to 14
and for Cno=13 the sequence number(3,4) of Lno is missing

i need to find out the missing sequence no's for the clno

Comment: Please share code you've already tried when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for generating range of numbers and then find missing ones:

```
with cte as (
    select t.CNo, min(t.Lno) as Lno, max(t.Lno) as max_Lno from Table1 as t
    group by t.CNo
    union all
    select c.CNo, c.Lno + 1 as Lno, c.max_Lno
    from cte as c
    where c.Lno < c.max_Lno
)
select c.Cno, c.Lno
from cte as c
where
    not exists (
        select *
        from Table1 as t
        where t.CNo = c.CNo and t.Lno = c.Lno
    )
order by 1, 2
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

if you have tables with sequential numbers, you can do this:

```
select c.Cno, n.n as Lno
from numbers as n
    inner join (
        select
            tt.CNo, min(tt.Lno) as min_Lno, max(tt.Lno) as max_Lno
        from Table1 as tt
        group by tt.CNo
    ) as c on c.min_Lno <= n.n and c.max_Lno >= n.n
where
    not exists (
        select *
        from Table1 as t
        where t.CNo = c.CNo and t.Lno = n.n
    )
order by 1, 2;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd194/4)</kbd>**

Comment: Ok downvoter would be great to hear your explanation. Is it because you don't understand what this query doing? :)

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but it seems you are not asking for what the maximum line number can be for each CNO (assuming that they are different) other than that this should be marked as the answer, have an upvote

Comment: @gh9 I don't see any requirements for max line number in OP question, and my SQL gives exact output he wants - from 4 to 14 for Cno 12 and 3 and 4 for Cno 13. Thanks for upvote :)

Comment: you are correct, but I assumed there is a max line. Since OP does not state one way or the other it would be a better answer if you provided a max line option.

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure what you are trying to do but you could use a number table to help with this.

if you have a table called numbers like this:

```
number 
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5.. up to highest number you are interested in
```

then you could do something like:

```
select 
    n.number
from
    numbers as n
    left outer join table as t
        on n.number = t.Lno
        and t.cno = 12
where
    n.number <= (select max(lno) from table where cno = 12)
    and t.nco is null
```

I don't know what type of output you are looking for or how you want to select the missing numbers you are looking for.